# how to run sql query based off what is selected in HTML dropdown that is populated with data from db

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, sql

I currently have a dropdown that is populated with options from a mySQL database and I would like to dynamically pass whatever is currently selected to a php function and print the result underneath the dropdown. For everything else I have a submit button that calls to a functions.php file but since this is a dropdown I cannot do that. I do believe I will need to use AJAX/Jquery in order to reference the values. I am just not sure how exactly I should do it. (Other solutions are welcome). Attached is the code that makes up my dropdown.

```
<form action="teampage.inc.php" method="POST">
    <div style="text-align: center;" class="split left">
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px">My Teams</p>
        <label for="your_teams">Select a team:</label>
        <select class="form-select" style="width: 200px; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" name="your_teams" id="your_teams" onchange="getSelectValue('your_teams');"> 
        <?php
        $pid1 = getUserData($_SESSION['username']);
        $pid2 = $pid1['id'];
        $q2 = 'SELECT `Team Name`  FROM Team WHERE Owner = :pid';
        $values = [':pid' => $pid2];
        try{
            $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($q2);
            $stmt2->execute($values);
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
        while($rows = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $teams = $rows['Team Name'];
                echo "<option value = '$teams'>$teams</option>";
            }

        ?>
        </select> 
        </form>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code for getSelectValue().

Comment: I suggest you use ids for the option values, and the displayable name as the content inside the option tag (only do escape html chars or you are leaving a security hole).  and do be sure when processing the form to verify that the team Owner is what you expect, don't just trust the id from the request

Comment: What @ysth said: use ids in options and escape EVERY PHP var that you put out. Example: `"<option value='".htmlspecialchars(teamId)."'>".htmlspecialchars(teamName)."</option>"`